# How to add drop down list in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I am using Joomla 1.7 and trying to create a website for a Real Estate Business. For that i need to have drop down lists for searching purpose. I am not getting how to place dropdown list in the page

and also please suggest me if any module is there for creating search options.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Real Estate - there is something called SOBI2 that you could check into.

It's more of an entire solution - not just a drop down solution.  But it has some of the pre-built search features that include drop-down selections for things like you mentioned.  I know of MANY people who use SOBI2 with real estate sites specifically.

The downside?  The free version is only 1.5 compatible.  However according to [the sobi2 forums](http://www.sigsiu.net/forum/community-board-for-discussions/sobi2-for-joomla-1-7/) the 'pro' version is 1.7 compatible.

Not sure if you wanted a commercial solution, but sobi2 is good stuff.

The alternative is you could create a menu item that is a search page - then create a template override ([read up on template overrides here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewforum.php?f=629)) for the search page and customize it however you would like.  It will take a bit of time - but should give you the results you want.

All of this depends on your level of familiarity with coding (if you have any experience).  There are always options but you didn't mention how familiar you are with this stuff so it's hard to give an accurate answer.

Comment: thank you very much. I am very new to Joomla, i do not have any kind of experience. So feeling it a bit tough. Eventhough i have created 2 sites here, i did not use search or any type of coding.

Comment: No problem.  Having a good solid understanding of HTML, PHP and the MVC architecture will benefit you with Joomla if you plan to edit a lot of things.  Joomla is really powerful so take the time to get to know it.  Glad I could help!